# sklearn agglomerative clustering: dynamically updating the number of clusters

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering

The documentation for sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering mentions that,

> when varying the number of clusters and using caching,
>   it may be advantageous to compute the full tree.

This seems to imply that it is possible to first compute the full tree, and then quickly update the number of desired clusters as necessary, without recomputing the tree (with caching).

However this procedure for changing the number of clusters does not seem to be documented. I would like to do this but am unsure how to proceed.

Update: To clarify, the fit method does not take number of clusters as an input:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.fit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set a cacheing directory with the paramater `memory = 'mycachedir'` and then if you set `compute_full_tree=True`, when you rerun `fit` with different values of `n_clusters`, it will used the cached tree rather than recomputing each time. To give you an example of how to do this with sklearn's gridsearch API:

```
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

ac = AgglomerativeClustering(memory='mycachedir', 
                             compute_full_tree=True)
classifier = GridSearchCV(ac, 
                          {n_clusters: range(2,6)}, 
                          scoring = 'adjusted_rand_score', 
                          n_jobs=-1, verbose=2)
classifier.fit(X,y)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however the fit method does not take n_clusters as input: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.fit

Comment: I had another look and it seems that the correct way to do it is via model.set_params(n_clusters=x) http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.set_params

Comment: you never pass parameters to the fit method, you set them when you're initializing your classifier, e.g. `ac = AgglomerativeClustering(memory='mycachedir', compute_full_tree=True, n_clusters=10)` (this is actually just what set_params is doing but it's an extra step you don't need)

Comment: Yes, but my aim is to dynamically update the number of clusters without recomputing the tree: it seems I can only do this with set_params.

Comment: The usual way to try different hyperparamters is via a gridsearch using `GridsearchCV`, give this a go with these settings, and hopefully it will used the cached tree (and your code will be a lot cleaner)

Comment: Thank you. If its possible to update your answer with this information, so I could accept it.

Comment: OK I've included a small example. does this make sense?

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old question, however the solution below might turn out helpful

```
# scores = input matrix

from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import cut_tree
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

linkage_mat = linkage(scores, method="ward")
euc_scores = euclidean_distances(scores)

n_l = 2
n_h = scores.shape[0]

silh_score = -2
# Selecting the best number of clusters based on the silhouette score
for i in range(n_l, n_h):
    local_labels = list(cut_tree(linkage_mat, n_clusters=i).flatten())
    sc = silhouette_score(
        euc_scores,
        metric="precomputed",
        labels=local_labels,
        random_state=42)
    if silh_score < sc:
        silh_score = sc
        labels = local_labels

n_clusters = len(set(labels))
print(f"Optimal number of clusters: {n_clusters}")
print(f"Best silhouette score: {silh_score}")
# ...
```