# sklearn agglomerative clustering compute_full_tree

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to cluster a matrix of longitude and latitude values with agglomerating clustering of sklearn library.

I want to calculate in how many clusters I have to divide my points to have a maximum distance of fifty meters. I calculate the maximum distance between the points of each clusters until, in all the clusters, there is a maximum distance of fifty meters. If not, I do a clustering with n_clusters + = 1

I calculate the tree and the clusters until I find the proper separation. I would like to not have to calculate the tree in each iteration because I lose a lot of computational time.

I would like to calculate the whole tree once using the function "compute_full_tree" and then just ask the groups indicating the number of clusters I want. It's possible?

```
cl = 1
while(max(maxDist) > 50):
    cl += 1
    labels = aglomerativeClust(X, cl)

    for l in range(len(X)):
        X[l].cluster = str(labels[l])

        clusters = [[] for o in range(max(labels)+1)]

        for x in X:
            clusters[int(x.cluster)].append(x)

        maxDist = [0. for o in range(max(labels)+1)]
        for m in range(len(clusters)):
            for x in clusters[m]:
                for y in clusters[m]:
                    dist=compute_vincenty_distance(x,y)
                    if(dist > maxDist[m]):
                        maxDist[m] = dist

def aglomerativeClust(Y, cl):
    X = []
    for y in Y:
        X.append([y.visit.latitude,y.visit.longitude])
    model = AgglomerativeClustering(linkage='complete',n_clusters=cl)
    model.fit(X)

    labels = model.labels_
    return labels
```

Comment: What about caching and computing the full tree? Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36491660/3429115).