# varying number of clusters without recalculating tree every time

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

We are using sklearn in python and trying to run agglomerative clustering (Wards) on a range of cluster numbers (i.e. N=2-9) using full_tree without having to re-compute the tree for each individual value of N, by using the cache. This was answered in an old post from 2016 but that answer doesn't seem to work anymore. See ([sklearn agglomerative clustering: dynamically updating the number of clusters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36490241/sklearn-agglomerative-clustering-dynamically-updating-the-number-of-clusters)).
 In other words, run fit over different values of N, without re-clustering every time. However, we are getting syntax errors and not able to call up the labels for any of the clusters stored in cache afterwards. Code looks something like:

```
x = AgglomerativeClustering(memory="mycachedir", compute_full_tree=True
```

but `x.fit_predict(inputDF{2})` does not fit the syntax of the memory access command
 Anybody know the syntax for calling up labels from the cache in this scenario? Thanks
P.S. I'm a newbie so apologies in advance if I am not being clear.

Tried solution posted in 2016 ([sklearn agglomerative clustering: dynamically updating the number of clusters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36490241/sklearn-agglomerative-clustering-dynamically-updating-the-number-of-clusters)).

Code looks something like:

```
x = AgglomerativeClustering(memory="mycachedir", compute_full_tree=True
```

but `x.fit_predict(inputDF{2})` does not fit the syntax of the memory access command

We expect to run clustering on a given array input and retrieve labels of each cluster when we vary the number of clusters "N" over a range, using the cache memory rather than re-computing the tree every time

Answer (score 0):

The sklearn API is badly suited for this.

It's much better to use agglomerative clustering from scipy. Because it consists of **two steps**: Building the linkage / dendrogram and then extracting a flat clustering from this. The first step is O(n³) with Ward, but the second step is only O(n) I think. A similar approach can be found in ELKI, too. But unfortunately, sklearn follows this narrow "fit-predict" view originating from classification, and that does not support such a two-step approach.

There is also other functionality available in scipy, but not in sklearn, if I am not mistaken. Just have a look.

Comment: Scipy looks like an interesting solution.  We will take a look at that.  Thanks