# How to specify the memory directory for Agglomerative clustering using sklearn

Tags: python, memory, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to optimise the computational time used for computing multiple results with different amounts of clusters on the same data set using sklearn's `AgglomerativeClustering`.

As indicated in [sklearn agglomerative clustering: dynamically updating the number of clusters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36490241/sklearn-agglomerative-clustering-dynamically-updating-the-number-of-clusters), it is possible to store the entire tree computed by `AgglomerativeClustering`. Then, you can respecify the `n_clusters`-parameter of the clustering object and simply extract the new clustering result of the same data set clustered into the new amount.

I am sorry if this is a trivial question, but I have very little experience with dealing with memory using Python. My question is how to specify the cache directory used by `AgglomerativeClustering`. In the example in the link above, it is written as:

```
AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=10, memory='mycachedir', compute_full_tree=True)
```

What is `'mycachedir'` exactly? Do I need to replace it by my own cache directory, or does python create a new directory somewhere called `'mycachedir'`? If so, is this removed when my program ends? I would like the cache be removed once my program stops or ends. Again, I am sorry if this obvious.

I tried to run it with the string `"mycachedir"` and Python does not raise an error. So where is this directory located? And how does it behave? E.g., is it removed once the program ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to scikit-learn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html#sklearn-cluster-agglomerativeclustering), "*if a string is given, it is the path to the caching directory.*"

As a matter of fact, caching is performed with the [`joblib.Memory`](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/blob/master/joblib/memory.py#L872) class of the [`joblib`](https://pypi.org/project/joblib/) package. The directory is created by `os.makedirs(os.path.expanduser(memory))` where `memory` is an `AgglomerativeClustering` input argument. Though, it can be deleted with `joblib.Memory.clear`, to the best of my knowledge, this is not the case when calling `AgglomerativeClustering.fit`.

Using `sklearn.AgglomerativeClustering` [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html#Example:%7E:text=with%20ward%20linkage.-,Examples,-%3E%3E%3E),

```
import os

# EXTERNALS
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
              [4, 2], [4, 4], [4, 0]])

memory_dir = "~/tmp/my_cached_memory_folder" 
# relative path depending on your working directory
# (cf. `os.getcwd()`)

clustering = AgglomerativeClustering(memory=memory_dir).fit(X)

full_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(memory_dir))

print("Cached memory directory: " f"{full_path}")
print(os.path.isdir(full_path))

# Cached memory directory: /home/remi_cuingnet/tmp/my_cached_memory_folder
# True
```

Note that you have to manually clear it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, could you write a couple of lines of code, that would work? E.g., should I initilise a a `joblib.Memory` object to pass to `AgglomerativeClustering`? And is it necessary to clear it manually afterwards or does this always happen when the program ends?